# Android MP4 playback issue from URL

Tags: android, android-video-player

I am trying to play mp4 video from URL but my phone always give me error "sorry this video can not be played" instead if i download video from same URL then video plays fine at phone.

http://beta-vidizmo.com/hilton.mp4

Please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: the video has to be properly encoded for android streaming. see http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: what do u mean by proper android streaming is there any tool available that can encode video for android streaming

Comment: not that I know off. The specs for video encoding are there in the doc

Comment: if it was a video encoding issue then video should not play after download isn't it?

Comment: i have tried recommended codecs by google to encode video but video is still not serving from URL. will u please encode one for me?

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the android version. Droid X and Samsung Captivate had a lot of trouble streaming MP4 files when it was in version 2.1, but after the Gingerbread update a lot of androids had this problem fixed.

Make sure you encode the video so that the moov atom is bought to the beginning. I think you can do this with QT Faststart.